# change of histogram to line plot by ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot the geom_histogram but as the plots overlap, I want to plot it linear instead of bars, i.e, the x=hp, y=count (percent).
Can anybody please help me find how to do it.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=5)
```

I have done it by qplot but I need to do it in ggplot and the percent.

```
  qplot(hp, data = mtcars, geom = "freqpoly", binwidth = 10)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_freqpoly`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=..count../sum(..count..))) + 
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth=5) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  ylab("Percent")
```

[image: geom_freqpoly plot]